# How to save graylog logs to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, graylog2, graylog, graylog3

I'm trying to output all the logs from a Graylog server stream to a mongodb server. There is a jdbc output plugin that stream to RDBMS using jdbc but how to save the logs to Mongodb. Graylog is saving configuration data and stream configuration to mongodb and logs at elastic search but I want to also save the logs to mongodb server for audit trail purpose.

Does somebody have an idea on how I could do it ?

Answer (score 0):

That is going to blow up the size of your MongoDB. Be sure to send it to an instance other than your Graylog instance to avoid trouble. Or cap the collection you store it in at a fairly aggressive number.

Comment: Thanks
but is there any option to move the logs to mongodb?

Comment: I don’t know. You could send them to Graylog via filebeat though.